# C# - Entity Framework - An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, stack-overflow

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

The below code is called on a success of this method:

```
internal static List<RivWorks.Model.Negotiation.ProductsSold> GetProductsSoldByCompany(Guid CompanyID)
{
    var ret = from a in _dbRiv.ProductsSold where a.Company.CompanyId == CompanyID select a;
    return ret.ToList();
}
```

On the return it calls into the Entity Model and tries to populate all foreign keyed objects (child objects).  The schema is [1 Company has 0 to many ProductsSold].  For some reason, the call into the following code just cascades on itself:

```
[global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("RIV_Model", "FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company")]
[global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
[global::System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public Company Company
{
    get
    {
        return ((global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships)(this)).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Company>("RIV_Model.FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company").Value;
    }
    set
    {
        ((global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships)(this)).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Company>("RIV_Model.FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company").Value = value;
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// There are no comments for Company in the schema.
/// </summary>
[global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference<Company> CompanyReference
{
    get
    {
        return ((global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships)(this)).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Company>("RIV_Model.FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company");
    }
    set
    {
        if ((value != null))
        {
            ((global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships)(this)).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedReference<Company>("RIV_Model.FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company", value);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first method makes a call to the second method.  The second method seems to call itself endlessly.

How do I fix this in EF?

Comment: looks to me like an issue with your mappings

Comment: What's with all the fully-qualified names? They make it unnecessarily difficult to understand what's going on.

Comment: the fully qualified names are from MS's generation of the code for EF...

Comment: uhm - yea.  I'm right there with you when you say it is an issue with my mappings.  Only I did not create those mappings in code - EF did.  THe schema is extrememly basic and straight forward.  [1 Company has 0 to many ProductsSold].  See, simple.  So why is EF getting a Company, get a ProductsSold, get a ProductsSold, get a ProductsSold, get a ProductsSold, ad naseum?

Comment: It's calling Company -> ProductsSold -> ProductsSold? There's no code related to ProductsSold in your snippet, so there might still be an issue. The code you did past looks very similar to the generated (and working) code in one of my projects.

Comment: Agreed with Sander; can you show the stack?

Comment: @Craig, I removed that comment, my question was to show the callstack (mentioning it again to 'fix' your comment)

Comment: One more thing to note, I would strongly advise against caching the db context in a static variable. The context is supposed to 'live' for a single unit-of-work. It's probably not causing this StackOverflow, but it can cause all kinds of nasty problems. I didn't even consider the multi-threading problems around this.

Comment: I cannot show the stack trace as I have a stack overflow.

Comment: I may have mistyped my comment.  Sorry.  In public Company Company it is executing the getter.  "GetRelatedReference<Company>("RIV_Model.FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company");".  This then drops into the getter for System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference<Company> CompanyReference.  The getter calls GetRelatedReference<Company>("RIV_Model.FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company");!!  This call then dropsinto the getter for System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference<Company> CompanyReference.  The getter calls GetRelatedReference<Company>("RIV_Model.FK_ProductsSold_Company", "Company");!!

Comment: Do you see the never ending loop now?  Once in the second getter it just keeps calling itself.

Comment: Please show the whole stack. Or at least until it starts cycling. You can do this with a breakpoint on the end of the cycle.

Comment: could you using return lines that the entire line be visible in your code for lisibility?

Comment: I've got a **TEMP FIX** in place.  I went into the database, dropped the relationships, regenrated the model in EF and now it works fine.  For me, that is proof positive the relationship call is the culprit.  Now to figure out **WHY** EF is doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 3 times at deleting and rebuilding my model from scratch, the stack overflow is magically gone.   <grrrrr />

Chalk it up to a bad wizard error somewhere along the line.

Comment: Same for me. Rebuilt the model and it was fixed

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same exact issue using Asp.net Mvc, Sql Server, and Linq to Entities.  Going through the callstack I saw that two of my repositories each had a new repository call in the other other repository. Example...

Repository1.cs

```
Respository2 repo2 = new Repository2();
```

Repository2.cs

```
Repository1 repo1 = new Repository1();
```

I guess a silly mistake on my part, not exactly sure whats going on (maybe someone can chime in here...) aside from the obvious but I took the Repository calls out and everything works just fine now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my life. this is exactly i have been doing in one of my repo. once again thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
internal static List<RivWorks.Model.Negotiation.ProductsSold> GetProductsSoldByCompany(Guid CompanyID) 
{ 
    var ret = from a in _dbRiv.Company where a.CompanyId == CompanyID select a.ProductsSolds; 
    return ret.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: This looks like a possibility.  Once I get some other fires put out I'll test this.  Thanks.

Comment: it will most likely solve the recursing, but it shouldn't be recursing in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the Company -> Company relation to be lazy loaded.

Answer (score -6):

The StackOverflow error is occurring due to endless Looping which uses the full cache memory and then at the end it show the stack overflow error.

The endless loop need to be stopped and it is not a best practice of calling the same function.

Optimize the code and try to avoid the Looping.

Comment: Hmmm.  So you are suggesting I go into the wizard created code and stop it there?  And what do I do the next time I build the project and EF rewrites the code for me?

Comment: @Shivkant, that's obvious and known. How do you propose a fix?