# Entity Framework -- An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll -- Why?

Tags: entity-framework, stack-overflow

I am trying to use entity framework to make a questionairre.  I cannot get the questionairre models to load at all -- each fails with a stackoverflowexception.

I have other models in other EDMX files, and they have worked fine so far.

`QuestionEntities qc = new QuestionEntities();
System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<FormView> qvs = qc.FormViews;`

The overflow happens on the second line.

As far as I can tell, they are all set for lazy load, so it should not be attempting to load the entire DB.  Just in case it has, I attempted to remove all recursive navigation properties, but it still fails.

The only similar entry I have found is [C# - Entity Framework - An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067866/c-entity-framework-an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-stackoverflowexcep)

Unfortunately, that one was only solved through repeatedly restarting the EDMX (which I have tried as well).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please look into your generated code, you may have some recursive property definition which may cause the problem. Stack Overflow only occurs in recursive call that ends up in endless loop.

If you post your model and generated code, then it will be easy to find cause of problem.

We did have same problem when there were tables that were recursively included in search, for example consider a tree kind of structure like file system, where directory contains children which are directories, such navigation properties fail to include and results in stack overflow.

Comment: As I said, I don't have any recursing elements in the model.  I will post it on my original question just the same.

Comment: Check for recursive navigation properties, which are like reference to same class as foreign key.

Comment: I already removed all relationships and navigation properties to make sure this wasn't an issue.

Comment: I never figured out my problem.  I completely restarted from scratch with a new copy of the database and a did the model from scratch again (I did copy/paste a few pieces) and the new version works.    Anyone else who has this problem (after you've checked for recursions) should just save the time and effort and restart. It seems to be something within the interworkings of entity framework.