# Linq Query throws System.StackOverflowException on .tolist()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, stack-overflow

The following code retrieves  data from my database:

```
var acc_count = (from p in db.Payee
where p.AccountNumber == "02055455622"
select p)
```

But when I try to run `acc_count.ToList()` or `acc_count.Count()`, I get a `System.StackOverflowExeption`.

---

This is the Payee Model Class. I'm using ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework Code First

```
public class Payee
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name="Account Number")]
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Bank Bank { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how you have defined your class `Payee` ?

Comment: Try to rebuild your EF designer and check it again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067866/c-sharp-entity-framework-an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-stackoverflo

Comment: Clean solution and rrefresh edmx model

Comment: Can you please add the definition of the Bank class here?

Answer (score 2):

I've finally been able to solve the issue. It wasn't the linq query that was throwing the exception. This is where the mistake came from

```
return Create(payee);
```

instead of

```
return View();
```

Because my

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create() {

}
```

did not have any input variable, it kept calling the other method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Models.Payee payee) {

}
```

So, that created an infinite loop which then led to the exception

Thanks guys